# What does selling rope mean?

Tags: lyrics

I was reading the lyrics of the song "Selling Rope" by "Los Campesinos" and there's a part that says:

> Anecdote, lie 
>   My own alibi 
>   I've been telling jokes 
>   Piled notes high
>   My own alibi
>   I've been selling rope

also

> Oh I was a bird right then, one day I will be again
>   I've been telling jokes while selling rope to you

so what does it mean? I made a google search and it is not an idiom or anything like that, is it a british slang or something?

Comment: Nothing I'm familiar with. Maybe "rope" = "hemp" = "marijuana"?

Comment: Seems related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6861/money-for-rope-meaning-and-derivation

Comment: See also: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdCE0s7-DuQ

Comment: Yea I also read that question but I don't understand what it means lol

Comment: "selling rope" is a variant of "money for old rope". It means getting paid by doing something easy or selling something that is perceived as having low value.

Comment: My first association was "giving someone enough rope to hang themselves" and how it would be even more damning if they paid you for that privilege.

Comment: I read the meaning of the song on the site songmeanings and apparently is talking about suicide, but why would he sell the rope to the other person?

Comment: @Loot In general, I would not recommend you take crowdsourced lyrics-interpreting sites like songmeanings as authorities. Anyone who has an opinion, or a crazy idea, or an opium dream, can submit their interpretations. And most of them are unresearched, just "personal interpretations".  Listen to the others above you: "selling rope" is a (presumably British?) idiom meaning "making easy money" (by doing low-value work).

Comment: Consult genius.com, which gives line by line breakdowns of song lyrics. For "selling rope", they have a competing analysis using the British idiom: http://genius.com/2340982

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/money-for-old-rope